How is succinct verification for transparent SNARKs possible?
I am a bit confused as to how succinct verification is possible with transparent SNARKs (i.e., SNARKs without trusted setup).
As I understand it, a transparent SNARK proof $\pi$ allows a verifier given a circuit $C$ and an input $x$ to verify that there exists an input $w$ such that $C(x, w)=1$. Succinctness should mean, in particular, that the time to verify $\pi$ is much smaller than $|C|$. But doesn't the verfier at least need to read the description of $C$? And doesn't that require at least time $|C|$?
(Note: with trusted setup, there is a verification key $vk$ that depends on $C$; the verifier takes $vk$ as input in addition to $\pi$. So I understand how succinct verification is possible there, since $vk$ ``encodes'' $C$. My question is specifically about the transparent setting.)

Take a look at this post https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68077/transparent-setup-of-snarks. It looks like random oracle is required.

$C$ can have a description much shorter than $|C|$, for the same reason that a short piece of code can run for a very long time. The size of $C$ accounts for all operations performed during a computation (on a worst-case choice of input). Consider for example an arithmetic circuit that computes $x^{2^t} \bmod n$ on input $x$: it took me one line to describe it, but the circuit has $t$ squaring steps$^*$, where $t$ could be arbitrarily large.
$*$: there's a circuit with less operations but it requires knowing the factorization of $n$.

I'm sorry for my confusion but why should all circuits have a short description? Is it the case that there is a short description for all poly-sized circuits? And is it easy for the verifier to find it?

All circuits do not have a short description and even when they do it is not easy in general to find one. A SNARK will give you a proof which is succinct in the witness size, but not in the statement size (since the verifier needs to at least agree on what the statement is). You can define such a SNARK for arbitrary languages/circuits, it will however be only useful/meaningful for the (many) statements whose description can be much shorter than the witness / circuit size.
